# How do I partition an empty SSD in Ubuntu during installation?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, ssd

I have Windows 10 installed on my 128 GB SSD, and I'm installing Ubuntu on my new 512 GB SSD. But my new SSD hasn't be partitioned yet, and I want to split it by half. One half of my new SSD will be for Ubuntu, and the other half will be for Windows 10 because I'm planning to reinstall Windows 10 on my new SSD and get rid of my old 128 GB SSD or use it to store anything.

I'm currently at the Ubuntu partitions page, and I need help. I don't want to create a swap, home, and other partitions. I will split my new SSD into two and only install Ubuntu on one half, and that's it.

512 GB SSD > 256 GB partition for Ubuntu, 256 GB partition for future reinstallation of Windows 10.

P.S. I'll use my Windows 10 on my old SSD by loading it in the boot

Thanks.

Comment: Make a 256 partition, format as ext4, mount point /, and all done.  Might need a small EFI ~300 to 500MB partition also.  Can format rest of drive as NTFS for Windows, or leave as free/unallocated space.

Comment: If UEFI be sure to use gpt partitioning. Windows only boots from gpt with UEFI and only from MBR with BIOS. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/whatsgpt.html & http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Installing an OS can be messy, make sure any files that you want to keep (even though it is on a different drive) have been backed up.*

I am guessing that you are going to use the BIOS to select boot drive and OS for right now. This will work as long as there is only one OS installed to a drive. Once you install two or more OS to a single drive then there will be some issues - read entire post.

**Short answer:**
Create two equal partitions. Assign the first partition as ext4 and mount point /

When you don't create any other partitions and mount points, everything gets dumped into one.

**Long answer:**
Boot Ubuntu and start the install. When you get to the partitioning options, select "Something Else". Select/highlight the new 512gb SSD and click on "New partition table". There will be a warning about "removing partitions...", click "Continue". That will create a new device under your drive called "free space". Select/highlight "free space" and click the "+" button.

```
Size (half of whatever number shown) in MB
Type for the new partition = primary
Location for the new partition = beginning of the space
Mount point = /
```

"Device for boot loader installation" should be the drive that Linux was installed to. This should always be the drive itself (example: /dev/sda) not a partition (example: /dev/sda1).

That is it, select "Install Now" and confirm that is what you really want.

**When you are ready to install Windows:**
Boot up the windows installer. Select "Custom install" and when it asks "Where do you want to install windows" select/click on "Drive # Unallocated space". Continue installing windows until complete. At this point MS Windows has removed grub and therefore cannot boot into ubuntu/linux now. To reinstall grub, boot up using ubuntu installer, select "Try Ubuntu" to get to the desktop version of ubuntu. Connect to the internet and install boot-repair.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

When boot-repair opens, select "Recommended repair". You will see a prompt to upload log to pastebin", that is up to you. Restart computer and Grub will be back. Windows installs several partitions and either Microsoft option would be fine.

**A more common method:**
Typically Windows is installed and then Linux is installed. Keep reading if you would like to learn more about that.

Microsoft Windows does NOT "see" ubuntu/ Linux, so Windows must be installed first otherwise ubuntu/linux and its boot will be overwritten.

You don't have to follow this order, but it will save a lot of time and avoid fixing boot partitions.

1. Install a clean install of Windows to the new SSD or clone the
   existing Windows from the old drive to the new one.
2. Boot up ubuntu or any Linux OS, and then proceed with installation.
3. When it comes time for partitions, choose a single one "Install Ubuntu alongside...".

Comment: You definitely should also put an EFI partition on the 512, because the OP is (eventually) getting rid of the 128. Locating grub there sadly still doesn't work from the installer (launchpad bug 1396379).